# MongoDB driver findOneAndUpdate method, how to return both values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Is there a way I can return both values for the findOneAndUpdate() method for the MongoDB driver?

Here is my Code:

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate({name: 'chris'}, {$set: {name: "matt"}}, {returnOriginal: false}, (err, result) =>{
        console.log(result) //returns matt, want to be able to return both chris and matt

    })
```

I want to get both the Chris and Matt values, so I can log to the console

```
Chris has been changed to matt in the db.
```

I can't seem to find a way currently and was wondering if anyone has solved this problem already.

Comment: Well where are they coming from to start with? Presumably they're not *actually* hardcoded (and if they are, just `console.log('Chris has been changed to matt in the db.')`).

Comment: ya, I'm just learning this on my own currently and am hard coding to begin with. I guess it would not be possible in this scenario? I cant seem to figure out a way lol.

I definitely see a way to code this dynamically in my head if I was doing this from an express app.get using the params throug.

Comment: Just extract those two names to variables, then you don't need to get them from the original or updated objects anyway. But no, the method only gives you the original *or* the updated document, you'd have to refactor if you wanted access to both at the same time.

Comment: thanks john, I just wasn't sure if there was a way or not. good to know. thanks agian

Comment: If you are using mongoose or mongoose is an option you can achieve something like that via `pre` & `post` hooks on the `update` operation.